# How to turn on tracing in a unit test using a ResourceTestRule?

Tags: dropwizard

I'm using dropwizard with jersey. I'm having a problem with the path in a resource and would like to debug it. How do you configure the jersey environment variable for this? The following does not work.

```
@ClassRule
public static final ResourceTestRule resources = ResourceTestRule.builder()
    .addResource(UserResource.class)
    .addProperty("jersey.config.server.tracing.type", "ON")
    .build();
```

Comment: Very much interested in the answer as well. If Jersey unit-test fails (returns wrong status-code for example) it is difficult to figure out why, because the test framework (Junit, Jersey or Dropwizard) only shows System.err prints and ERROR-logs on the test console.

Would want also to display INFO logs, but don't know how to enable them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following call in `ResourceTestRule` sets up the default logging with `WARN` level:

```
static {
    BootstrapLogging.bootstrap();
}
```

To override, I call `BootstrapLogging` again and indicate the required logging level in my test class after the `ResourceTestRule` creation, e.g.:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import io.dropwizard.logging.BootstrapLogging;
...

@ClassRule
public static final ResourceTestRule resources = ResourceTestRule.builder()
    .addResource(UserResource.class)
    .build();

static {
    BootstrapLogging.bootstrap(Level.DEBUG);
}
```

Then I can see my logging output in the console.